# dominoes in $4\times4$ square grid

Tags: combinatorics, tiling, polyomino

[image]

is there an organized way to count the possibilities, or just trial and error. Thanks!

Comment: Think about the various ways to pick two squares to be removed so that it is now *impossible* to cover the rest of the board with $7$ dominos

Answer (score 3):

HINT

Imagine the board is like a checkers board, with alternating black and white squares. ... you take it from there ....

Comment: Thank you for the checker board analogy - that solves it. 16C2 - 2x 8C2=64

Comment: @user526427 Yes. Or, a little more simply: any one black square and any one white square works (make sure to prove that)  so that's $8 \times 8=64$ possibilities.

Comment: that's right - even simpler

Comment: @user526427 :) Again, I want to stress that you need to prove that with one white and one black square removed, you can *always* tile the rest of the board with domino stones.  That is, it is trivial to see how with two blacks or with two whites removed you *cannot* tile it .... but that does *not* mean that with any one white and any one black you *can* ... so you need to have a proof for that... which is not hard ... but not trivial either. Let me know if you want a hint for that.